# How to prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^3x^2}{e^{nx}}$ converges to zero $\forall x\in[0;+\infty)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

> Show that
>   $$
> \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^3x^2}{e^{nx}}=0\ \ \ \forall x\in[0;+\infty)
> $$

The thing is I clearly understand that $e^{nx}$ grows faster than $n^3x^2$ but I cannot come up with any formal solution.

P.S. As for $x=0$, the answer is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [**ratio test**](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-ratio-test-for-sequence-convergence) for $x>0$ we obtain

$$\frac{(n+1)^3x^2}{e^{(n+1)x}}\frac{e^{nx}}{n^3x^2}=\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^3\frac1{e^x}\to \frac1{e^x}<1$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $e^{nx} \geq \frac {n^{4}x^{4}} {4!}$ (from the series expansion).

Answer (score 0):

If $x=0$ it is trivial. If $x>0$ you can write

$$
\frac{{n^3 x^2 }}
{{e^{nx} }} = \frac{{n^3 x^3 }}
{{e^{nx} }}\frac{1}
{x} = \frac{{t^3 }}
{{e^t }}\frac{1}
{x}
$$
where $t=nx$. As $n \to +\infty$ you have that $t\to +\infty$ and it is well known that
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to  + \infty } \frac{{t^3 }}
{{e^t }} = 0
$$
thus
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to  + \infty } \frac{{t^3 }}
{{e^t }}\frac{1}
{x} = \frac{1}
{x}\mathop {\lim }\limits_{t \to  + \infty } \frac{{t^3 }}
{{e^t }} = 0
$$